# How to get HTML input values in Javascript correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML input elements. I need to get an output by add those input values together. I created a JavaScript function to do that but, the output is "NaN" always.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="value1" /> <br/>
<input type="text" id="value2" /> <br/>
<button id="button1" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function calc()
{
    var x1 = document.getElementById('value1');
    var x2 = document.getElementById('value2');
    var r = x1+x2;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=r;
}
```

How do I get the real output here?

Comment: Start using jQuery. It easy and fast to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just edit the variables x1 and x2 into:

```
var x1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
var x2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
```

Comment: Thanx It worked

Comment: This leaves the web page open to cross-site scripting attacks. Imagine if someone gave value1 an input of `<img src="xxx" onerror="doSomethingEvil()" />`. You also need to check that the input is a valid number.

Comment: Thanx, but I just needed to edit my code to work it and this solved it. My task is very small one so I need only a few code.

Comment: Is this code on a publicly viewable website? If so, you need to secure it, or you are putting your users at risk.

Comment: No this is just for testing purpose. I'll add validation methods later :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the **value** attribute of the input.  **document.getElementById** returns a reference to the input itself.  Also, avoid using the **onclick** attribute, it is better to separate the logic from the HTML with **addEventListener**.

This code uses **parseInt** to convert the value from the inputs to a number.  You could also use **parseFloat**.  The **isNaN** check ensures both submitted values are numeric.  **isNaN** returns true if the value it tests is not a number.

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      var x1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('value1').value);
      var x2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('value2').value);
      if (isNaN(x1) || isNaN(x2)) {
        alert('Both values must be numeric');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = x1 + x2;
      }
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="value1" /> <br/>
<input type="text" id="value2" /> <br/>
<button id="button1">Calculate</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```